# Using Recursion given m(i)=1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5... + 1/i

Tags: java, recursion

This is what I have so far. I can't tell exactly how to change the numbers so it makes sense. Do I need to include the index as part of the equation? Although it seems like n1(the previous number) + (1/n2) should give me a new n2. Any thoughts?

```
package myrecursivemethod;

public class MyRecursiveMethod {

private static double index = 0;
private static double stoppingPoint=10;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   double n1= 0;
   double n2= 1;
   System.out.println("index: " + index + "->" + n1 );
   myRecursiveMethod(n1, n2);

}
 public static void myRecursiveMethod(double n1, double n2)
 {
     System.out.println("index: " + index + " -> " + (n1+(1/n2)));

     if (index == stoppingPoint)
         return; 
     index ++;

     myRecursiveMethod(n2, n1+(1/n2));
 }

}
```

Comment: Try printing out all the variables, and then consider whether that really seems correct.

Comment: Try not to use any static (or non-static) fields in your method. This task can be done with method with only one parameter like `double m(double i)`. Try to look at formula this way `m(4) = (1+1/2+1/3)+1/4` which means that `m(4) = m(3) + 1/i`. Now try to generalize it.

Comment: @Pshemo I would turn that into an answer, some viewers don't read the comments

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at your formula little closer and try to find a way to present this formula using similar formula with different arguments. For instance

```
sum(i) =  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (i-1) + i
```

is same as

```
sum(i) = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (i-1)) + i
```

but since

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (i-1) = sum(i-1)
```

we can rewrite entire formula as

```
sum(i) = sum(i-1) + i
```

(or actually)

```
         { sum(i-1) + i     if i>0 
sum(i) = {
         { 0                if i==0
```

Formula from your question is very similar to this one and can be presented in similar (recursive) way.